# Outlook mail integration with .net Desktop application

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, windowsformsintegration

I have window application running on my system in which i can send  mail through anywhere
but i want to integrate my application to outlook.

**1.Sent mail should be show in outlook sent mail folder.
2.In case mail sending is fail it should display in outbox folder of outlook**

Comment: Depending on your project you might want to consider building an Outlook AddIn instead? See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668191.aspx

Answer (score 1):

**Go through following code:**

```
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

if (this.listViewContacts.SelectedItems != null &&
this.listViewContacts.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
Outlook.ContactItem oRecip = (Outlook.ContactItem)
(this.listViewContacts.SelectedItems[0].Tag);

Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)
(oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
email.Recipients.Add(oRecip.Email1Address);
email.Subject = "Just wanted to say...";
email.Body = "Have a great day!";

if (MessageBox.Show(
"Are you sure you want to send a good day message to " +
oRecip.Email1DisplayName + "?", "Send?",
MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel)
== DialogResult.OK)
{
try
{
((Outlook.MailItem)email).Send();
MessageBox.Show("Email sent successfully.", "Sent");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show("Email failed: " + ex.Message,
"Failed Send");
}
}

oRecip = null;
email = null;
}
```

**Referance Link:**

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_misc/e-mail/article.php/c14293/Microsoft-Outlook-Integration-with-CNET.htm#page-2

Step by step implementation and explaination is given in this link.

Hope its helpful.